# rsync --link-dest from a file

Tags: rsync

I am attempting to create a simple backup script and I'm struggling to get `rsync` to do incremental backups.

I don't want it to overwrite files in the current backup but to link to the old ones, and if there's anything different between my current files and the last backup to create a new one with only the changed files listed.

So far I have tried the following command.

```
rsync -argptcvn --link-dest= 'cat /media/backup/$USER/lastbackup.log'
```

My command program adds the last successful backup name to a file called `lastbackup.log`; what I want to do is to get `--link-dest` to read the contents of that file before creating the next backup folder

However unless I put the full file path into the `--link-dest` path it shows the message

```
--link-dest arg does not exist:
```

I have also tried using redirection to take the contents of the file however that fails with the same message.

Answer (score 3):

> However unless i put the full file path into the --link-dest path it shows the message
>
> --link-dest arg does not exist:

Thats actually good. The --link-dir option works, the path exists.

```
'cat /media/backup/$USER/lastbackup.log'
```

is the problem. **The expression just isn't evaluated**.

You might want to try

```
`cat /media/backup/$USER/lastbackup.log`
```

or

```
( cat /media/backup/$USER/lastbackup.log )
```

Comment: I have edited the script as suggested and the incremental backup now works. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: I'm glad to read that! I like it when things work. By the way: You can "accept" answers if they solve your problem ;)